# Prevent IIS7 rewrite from adding "index.php" to path on redirect?

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am trying to configure [rewrite](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/) rules for a Wordpress MU 2.7 on IIS7 with PHP5 (fastcgi).

At the moment I only have the following rewrite rule in Web.config:

```
         <rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url="(.*)" />
             <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true"
                      pattern="^subdomain\.example\.com$" />
             </conditions>
             <action type="Redirect"
                     url="http://subdomain.example.com/{R:1}"
                     redirectType="Permanent" />
         </rule>
```

At the moment when I enter a URL (see below) it does **redirect** to the right hostname but for some reason prepends the path with a `index.php/`:

```
url: `http://subdomain/my/path/123`
redirects to: `http://subdomain.example.com/index.php/my/path/123`
should redirect to: `http://subdomain.example.com/my/path/123`
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is and how I can prevent this from happening?

Am I missing a certain server setting or something...? php.ini? web.config rule? Or is it just my rewrite rule that's wrong?

Edit: This problem seems to have nothing to do with Wordpress's permalink structure! The behaviour is the same if I remove of redirect `index.php`. I don't think any PHP code is running... this has to be at a higher level.

Comment: What settings do you have in Wordpress for permalink structure?

Comment: Does it matter?
At the moment I still get 404 errors for both urls because I've taken all other rules out and the subfolders are not found obviously; no php is running yet.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress, by default (I think), formats friendly permalinks as index.php/path/to/post, as this mimics rewriting without requiring the server to support rewriting. That would explain why your rewrites are that way - they have the index.php in them before being rewritten.

Comment: I don't think any php code (wordpress) runs. If I remove/rename index.php I still have the same problem. Besides that the permalink structure is already set to a version without "index.php" in the path...

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent it from happening by [changing the Permalink structure](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/466/enabling-pretty-permalinks-in-wordpress/) option in your WordPress config.

Comment: This was my first thought as well but it seems to be at a higher level... the permalink structure is already set to a version without /index.php in the path.